# Can you explain to me how to decompose this persistence module and why?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, data-analysis, persistent-homology

I am learning topological data analysis on my own. I am currently basically watching [This course](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF556/). But there this thing in the course note that I didn't understand.

So for this persistence module:

$$
\mathbb{K}^1 \stackrel{\quad\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right) \quad}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^3 \stackrel{\quad\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right) \quad}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^1
$$

A theorem tells me that I can decompose this as direct sum of interval modules in an unique way. But I don't know how this it possible for this example nor how this is unique. In the course note, it is decomposed as intervals [1, inf], [2, 3], [2, 3]. But I think the direct sum of these would be

$$
\mathbb{K}^1 \stackrel{\quad\left(\begin{array}{lll} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right) \quad}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^3 \stackrel{\mathrm{Id}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^3
$$

I have also an additional question, after decomposing, the intervals that I get are the barcodes, right?

Please help me. Thanks!

Theorem 1. A persistence module $\mathbb{V}$ can be decomposed as a direct sum of interval module, written as:
$$
\mathbb{V} \simeq \bigoplus \mathbb{I}_{\left[b_j, d_j\right]}
$$
in the following case (sufficient, not necessary):

1. If $T$ is finite. [Gabriel, 72].
2. When all the vector spaces $V_t$ are finite-dimensional, [Crowley-Boevey, 2012].
   Furthermore, when it exists, the decomposition is unique (up to isomorphism and ordering of terms).

Comment: I assume you look at persistence modules indexed over the natural numbers. 
I think your issue is with the convention what $[2,3]$ means. Is 3 the largest index where a class is nonzero or the smallest index where it is send to zero?

Comment: Yes I have question on this convention. But either way, the direct sum wouldn't be the the first persistence module that we want. @HenrikRüping

Comment: So with the convention that it is the smallest index, where it is send to zero, we would get
$\mathbb{K}^1 \stackrel{\quad\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right) \quad}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^3 \stackrel{\quad\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right) \quad}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{K}^1$, right? Thus it remains to show that this persistence module is isomorphic to the one given in the question.

Comment: Yes. Please show me the isomorphism. If this was 3 $\mathrm{id}$ between 3 $\mathbb{K}$, it wouldn't satisfy the commutativity property. And moreover, I think [1, 3], [2, 3], [2, inf] would work as a decomposition, too. How come the uniqueness?

Comment: Sorry to bother. Just to make a notification. @HenrikRüping